# scanf(parameter) == 1 vs 1 == scanf(parameter) makes no difference?

Tags: c, return-value, scanf

I am really confused that when this like `1 == scanf("%lg", &entry)` is swapped to `scanf("%lg", &entry) == 1` makes no difference. My lab book says the former, while I feel latter is comprehensible.

`1 == scanf("%lg", &entry)` means `1` MUST be equal to `scanf("%lg", &entry)`Can anyone explain this? I understand the latter, that the evaluation of `scanf("%lg", &entry)` must equal `1`

I tried passing lots of different values and it makes no difference.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void) {
    double entry = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    int number_of_entries = 0;
    while (scanf("%lg", &entry) == 1  ) {
    total += entry;
    number_of_entries++;
    }
    /* print the average of all the entries */
    printf("%f\n", total / number_of_entries);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: They're called [Yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should not be surprised by `(1 == scanf(...))` behaving the same as `(scanf(...) == 1)`, since equality is [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation). However, this is so because one of the operands is idempotent (in particular, the literal constant `1`). `scanf()` is the only expression with a side effect, so there is no possibility of a different interpretation of the code when the arguments of `==` are reversed.

However, the evaluation order of the arguments to `==` is unspecified. So, if on side of `==` has a side effect that can affect the other side, then the evaluation order will impact the result of the `==` operation, and reversing the arguments could cause a different behavior. Such a program will thus have undefined behavior.

As a silly example, consider:

```
a = 0;
if (scanf("%d", &a) == a) {
    ...
}
```

The snippet has undefined behavior, because it is unspecified whether the `a` on the right hand side of `==` will be the old value it was initialized to in the statement above, or the new value that the `scanf()` call may have supplied. Changing the order of the arguments may cause the program to behave differently, but the behavior is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%lg", &entry) == 1
```

is the same as

```
1 == scanf("%lg", &entry)
```

However, I once had a friend who preferred the

```
1 == scanf("%lg", &entry)
```

because it caught the potential typo

```
1 = scanf("%lg", &entry)
```

whereas

```
scanf("%lg", &entry) = 1
```

would go through the compiler ok.

Comment: x == 5 however is not same as 5 == x, is it?

Comment: Sure. x == 5 is the same as 5 == x.

Comment: Okay, got rid of my confusion. It is equals

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. And it's not limited to `scanf`. Usage like

```
if (5 == x)
```

is called [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). It's a method to prevent forgetting to use double `=` to compare equality. If one mistakenly write:

```
if (5 = x)
```

Then the compiler will report the error. On the other hand

```
if (x = 5)
```

is valid C (it will assign `x` with the value of `1`, and return the value `5`, i.e, true) so the compiler may not warn your about it.

It's just a coding-style, many modern compilers will warn you if you write `if (x = 5)`. If that is true in your case, I suggest not using Yoda Conditions since it's bad for readability.